# Taking a row from a pandas DataFrame and adding it to a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a DataFrame with with 14 columns (with headers). I'd like to take the values of a row of this DataFrame at an index that's a random integer between 0 and the maximum length of the DataFrame, extract those values, and then add them to a new DataFrame with the same headers.

The data frame looks something like this:

[image]
I've tried using various combinations with .iloc, but for some reason that produces a DataFrame that's nothing but column headers, not the actual numerical values of the DataFrame itself.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal input/output example for clarity (in a reproducible format!)

Comment: You likely want `df2 = df.sample(n=1, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have same dummy dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'one'],
                   'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'D': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
```

Let's create an emplty df:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
```

If you want take a row from df to df2 then just do this:

```
df2 = df2.append(df.iloc[1], ignore_index=True)
# if append is deprecated you can do this:
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df.iloc[[1]]], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

If you want a random one you can do:

```
df2 = df2.append(df.sample(1), ignore_index=True)
#or
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df.sample(1)], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: `append` is deprecated, it will be removed in a future version. `df2 = df.sample(n=1, ignore_index=True)` is sufficient

Comment: Ok thank you, I did't know that append is deprecated, I guess my version of pandas may be a little old. I updated my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dataframe is named `df`, you should be able to query a specific row using `iloc`, *e.g.*:

```
df.iloc[[i]]
```

Where `i` is your random number.

You can then concatenate this dataframe with your new dataframe `df_new`.

```
for i in np.random.randint(0,10,size=10):
    if df_new.empty:
        df_new = df.iloc[[i]]
    else:
        df_new = pd.concat([df_new, df.iloc[[i]]])
```